# Can I redirect all messages from an interface on port 53 to a different port?

Tags: networking

I have a device connected via USB tethering, on interface `enp0s20f0u7`. I'd like to set up a DNS server for it with dnsmasq, however, I can't launch dnsmasq because some process is already using port 53 (`systemd-resolve`).

1. I don't want to disable or mess with `systemd-resolve`.
2. I'm not at liberty to configure the client device to make DNS requests on a port other than port 53.

I can run dnsmasq on some other port like 54. Is there a way I can, on my computer (the server), map all messages on port 53 from `enp0s20f0u7` to port 54, so that the DNS requests will go through without my client device being any the wiser?

Comment: Good question and I think it should be possible with iptables, but I dont know enough about iptables to post an answer. Curious to see how this question gets answered. +1

Comment: It's possible with an `iptables` change, however the question of importance is what device is making the DNS request and are you actually configured to properly have it make requests to your host system?  Because `systemd-resolve` only binds to `localhost` it wouldn't reply to requests for other devices.

Comment: @ThomasWard I'm not sure I understand you. I don't intend to have `systemd-resolve` respond to this tethered device, I want to run my own DNS server on a non-standard port (for the correct interface) and have the tethered device somehow go through that DNS server. If it's relevant, right now the tethered device at least sees mappings that I put in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: No, I mean that systemd-resolve shouldn't interfere with dnsmasq as they listen on different ports.  As for this, `dnsmasq` could do this, but unless you've *configured* the tethered device properly with proper DNS settings on the network interface for the device *and* got it to selectively determine which DNS servers to use based on connections (computers can do this, not many other devices/tethers) it's going to be a lot more complicated than you think to do this.  Usually since tethering is the opposite way - computer to device, not device to computer in that direction.

Comment: @ThomasWard Ah, you're saying that without special config on the device, it will likely not attempt to make DNS requests to my computer on port 53 in any case?

Comment: @JackM Correct.

Comment: Yep, please specify what the goal is. Your question smells as good as an XY problem

Comment: @cmak.fr The goal is simply to connect this device via USB, allow it to access the internet, and make it so requests from that device to `example.com` map to an IP of my choice. I could actually do this by just modifying `/etc/hosts/` on my computer, but ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't involve modifying system config. Ideally I'd like to have a process that I can launch on my computer which will set up the domain mapping for the tethered device, and when I stop the process the domain mapping will be unmapped, like a server.